# Upload de Imagens PHP e Ajax mandar caminho do arquivo para Input

Tags: php, ajax

Estou usando um sistema de upload de imagens que achei na internet, me serve muito! Além de fazer o upload das imagens, ele redimensiona e facilita o trabalho de quem usa.

A questão é a seguinte:

Tenho um formulário com alguns `inputs`, estes devem ser preenchidos com o caminho da imagem no servidor. Com um outro sistema que eu utilizava, a imagem aparecia e bastava o usuário clicar com o botão direito do mouse e copiar o endereço da imagem. Ficou difícil para mais de 50% deles.

Pensei comigo: Será que consigo mandar o caminho direto para o input? Já pesquisei muito na internet, mas sem resultado. Por isso, recorro aos gurus desta comunidade.

Caso eu esteja equivocado, existe alguma solução para esta questão?

Bom, vamos aos códigos:

O arquivo **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cadastro de Foto</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/resize.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Iniciando biblioteca
        var resize = new window.resize();
        resize.init();

        // Declarando variáveis
        var imagens;
        var imagem_atual;

        // Quando carregado a página
        $(function ($) {

            // Quando selecionado as imagens
            $('#imagem').on('change', function () {
                enviar();
            });

        });

        /*
         Envia os arquivos selecionados
         */
        function enviar()
        {
            // Verificando se o navegador tem suporte aos recursos para redimensionamento
            if (!window.File || !window.FileReader || !window.FileList || !window.Blob) {
                alert('O navegador não suporta os recursos utilizados pelo aplicativo');
                return;
            }

            // Alocando imagens selecionadas
            imagens = $('#imagem')[0].files;

            // Se selecionado pelo menos uma imagem
            if (imagens.length > 0)
            {
                // Definindo progresso de carregamento
                $('#progresso').attr('aria-valuenow', 0).css('width', '0%');

                // Escondendo campo de imagem
                $('#imagem').hide();

                // Iniciando redimensionamento
                imagem_atual = 0;
                redimensionar();
            }
        }

        /*
         Redimensiona uma imagem e passa para a próxima recursivamente
         */
        function redimensionar()
        {
            // Se redimensionado todas as imagens
            if (imagem_atual > imagens.length)
            {
                // Definindo progresso de finalizado
                $('#progresso').html('Imagen(s) enviada(s) com sucesso');

                // Limpando imagens
                limpar();

                // Exibindo campo de imagem
                $('#imagem').show();

                // Finalizando
                return;
            }

            // Se não for um arquivo válido
            if ((typeof imagens[imagem_atual] !== 'object') || (imagens[imagem_atual] == null))
            {
                // Passa para a próxima imagem
                imagem_atual++;
                redimensionar();
                return;
            }

            // Redimensionando
            resize.photo(imagens[imagem_atual], 800, 'dataURL', function (imagem) {

                // Salvando imagem no servidor
                $.post('ajax/salvar.php', {imagem: imagem}, function() {

                    // Definindo porcentagem
                    var porcentagem = (imagem_atual + 1) / imagens.length * 100;

                    // Atualizando barra de progresso
                    $('#progresso').text(Math.round(porcentagem) + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', porcentagem).css('width', porcentagem + '%');

                    // Aplica delay de 1 segundo
                    // Apenas para evitar sobrecarga de requisições
                    // e ficar visualmente melhor o progresso
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        // Passa para a próxima imagem
                        imagem_atual++;
                        redimensionar();
                    }, 1000);

                });

            });
        }

        /*
         Limpa os arquivos selecionados
        */
        function limpar()
        {
            var input = $("#imagem");
            input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <h1>Envie sua Foto:</h1>

    <form method="post" action="#" role="form">

        <div class="progress">
            <div id="progresso" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0"
                 aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input id="imagem" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple/>
            </div>

        </div>

    </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

O arquivo **salvar.php**

```
<?php

// Recuperando imagem em base64
// Exemplo: data:image/png;base64,AAAFBfj42Pj4
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];

// Separando tipo dos dados da imagem
// $tipo: data:image/png
// $dados: base64,AAAFBfj42Pj4
list($tipo, $dados) = explode(';', $imagem);

// Isolando apenas o tipo da imagem
// $tipo: image/png
list(, $tipo) = explode(':', $tipo);

// Isolando apenas os dados da imagem
// $dados: AAAFBfj42Pj4
list(, $dados) = explode(',', $dados);

// Convertendo base64 para imagem
$dados = base64_decode($dados);

// Gerando nome aleatório para a imagem
$nome = md5(uniqid(time()));

// Salvando imagem em disco
file_put_contents("../img/{$nome}.jpg", $dados);
```

Isso é muito importante pra mim, pois vou usar este código em todos os projetos, pela facilidade de uso. Ele manda o arquivo com muita facilidade, até os usuários com pouco conhecimento consegue utilizar (acredite, por aqui tem muitos!).

Comment: Cole os códigos diretamente na pergunta. Ou o trecho que você está tendo dificuldades. Caso tenha dúvidas, leia [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](/help/mcve)

Comment: Fiquei com medo de ficar muito grande, por isso fiz assim. Farei como recomendaste, amigo. Um instante, por favor.

Comment: Hebert se for grande, adicione apenas trechos pertinentes a sua dúvida. Dê uma lida no link que eu mandei, caso tenha dúvidas.

Comment: Ok, @DiegoFelipe. Eu ainda estou aprendendo a postar aqui. Na verdade, minha dúvida é uma só: Como poderia pegar o nome do arquivo que foi pra pasta do servidor e jogar num input. Tentei apenas explicar com mais detalhes...

Comment: Ele salva a imagem aqui: `file_put_contents("../img/{$nome}.jpg", $dados);` Preciso pegar esse nome de arquivo e jogar num input, mas não estou conseguindo achar um jeito de fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conseguir recuperar os dados da imagem você precisar fazer alterações em sua requisição ajax e na resposta do servidor.

**Alterações lado cliente**

[$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) permite que você capture a resposta do servidor, simplesmente adicionando um parâmetro em sua função de callback.

```
$.post('ajax/salvar.php', {imagem: imagem}, function(response) {
```

Nesse caso a resposta da requisição deve ser retornado para variável **response**

**Alterações lado Servidor**

O servidor por sua vez deve retornar os dados necessários para o seu javascript.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$data = array('foo' => 'bar');
echo json_encode($data);
die();
```

Esse código retorna um objeto JSON com atributo **foo** de valor **bar**

**Exemplo prático**

Utilizando o seu código como base, um exemplo que deve retornar o nome do arquivo e exibi-lo em um **console.log**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cadastro de Foto</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/resize.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Iniciando biblioteca
        var resize = new window.resize();
        resize.init();

        // Declarando variáveis
        var imagens;
        var imagem_atual;

        // Quando carregado a página
        $(function ($) {

            // Quando selecionado as imagens
            $('#imagem').on('change', function () {
                enviar();
            });

        });

        /*
         Envia os arquivos selecionados
         */
        function enviar()
        {
            // Verificando se o navegador tem suporte aos recursos para redimensionamento
            if (!window.File || !window.FileReader || !window.FileList || !window.Blob) {
                alert('O navegador não suporta os recursos utilizados pelo aplicativo');
                return;
            }

            // Alocando imagens selecionadas
            imagens = $('#imagem')[0].files;

            // Se selecionado pelo menos uma imagem
            if (imagens.length > 0)
            {
                // Definindo progresso de carregamento
                $('#progresso').attr('aria-valuenow', 0).css('width', '0%');

                // Escondendo campo de imagem
                $('#imagem').hide();

                // Iniciando redimensionamento
                imagem_atual = 0;
                redimensionar();
            }
        }

        /*
         Redimensiona uma imagem e passa para a próxima recursivamente
         */
        function redimensionar()
        {
            // Se redimensionado todas as imagens
            if (imagem_atual > imagens.length)
            {
                // Definindo progresso de finalizado
                $('#progresso').html('Imagen(s) enviada(s) com sucesso');

                // Limpando imagens
                limpar();

                // Exibindo campo de imagem
                $('#imagem').show();

                // Finalizando
                return;
            }

            // Se não for um arquivo válido
            if ((typeof imagens[imagem_atual] !== 'object') || (imagens[imagem_atual] == null))
            {
                // Passa para a próxima imagem
                imagem_atual++;
                redimensionar();
                return;
            }

            // Redimensionando
            resize.photo(imagens[imagem_atual], 800, 'dataURL', function (imagem) {

                // Salvando imagem no servidor
                $.post('ajax/salvar.php', {imagem: imagem}, function(response) {

                    //Exibindo os dados da resposta do servidor
                    console.log( response.photo );

                    // Definindo porcentagem
                    var porcentagem = (imagem_atual + 1) / imagens.length * 100;

                    // Atualizando barra de progresso
                    $('#progresso').text(Math.round(porcentagem) + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', porcentagem).css('width', porcentagem + '%');

                    // Aplica delay de 1 segundo
                    // Apenas para evitar sobrecarga de requisições
                    // e ficar visualmente melhor o progresso
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        // Passa para a próxima imagem
                        imagem_atual++;
                        redimensionar();
                    }, 1000);

                }, 'json');//O parâmetro JSON informa ao Jquery para tratar a resposta como um JSON

            });
        }

        /*
         Limpa os arquivos selecionados
        */
        function limpar()
        {
            var input = $("#imagem");
            input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <h1>Envie sua Foto:</h1>

    <form method="post" action="#" role="form">

        <div class="progress">
            <div id="progresso" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0"
                 aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input id="imagem" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple/>
            </div>

        </div>

    </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**salvar.php**

```
<?php

//Alterações no header preferencialmente são a primeira coisa no script
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Recuperando imagem em base64
// Exemplo: data:image/png;base64,AAAFBfj42Pj4
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];

// Separando tipo dos dados da imagem
// $tipo: data:image/png
// $dados: base64,AAAFBfj42Pj4
list($tipo, $dados) = explode(';', $imagem);

// Isolando apenas o tipo da imagem
// $tipo: image/png
list(, $tipo) = explode(':', $tipo);

// Isolando apenas os dados da imagem
// $dados: AAAFBfj42Pj4
list(, $dados) = explode(',', $dados);

// Convertendo base64 para imagem
$dados = base64_decode($dados);

// Gerando nome aleatório para a imagem
$nome = md5(uniqid(time()));

// Salvando imagem em disco
file_put_contents("../img/{$nome}.jpg", $dados);

//Resposta do servidor em json
$data = array('photo' => $nome);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Ele realmente mostra o nome do arquivo no console, mas sem a extensão e sem o caminho. Isso é o de menos, o caminho é o mesmo e a extensão também, posso colocar. Mas, preciso dessa informação num input, como faria isso? Baseado na sua solução, estou procurando informações na net, mas tenho pouquíssimo conhecimento em javascript...

Comment: @Herbert Richard para adicionar o nome da foto no Input, basta alterar o `console.log( response.photo );` do retorno pelo código de substituir o Input.Existe diversas formas de alterar o input, por isso não quis usar forma **x** ou **y** e deixar que você aplicasse a forma que acredita mais indicada, por mim usaria o bom e velho **Jquery** `$('#id_do_input').val( response.photo );`.

Comment: Tudo bem, meu amigo. Na verdade, eu não tinha uma forma preferida. Vou testar essa solução e retorno em instantes...

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Agora, só preciso colocar no código o caminho completo do servidor. Vou inserir ele manualmente no código, sem problemas. Minha única preocupação no momento é que, no mesmo arquivo, tenho vários uploads de imagem. Mas vou ver o que faço e retorno caso tenha alguma dúvida adicional. Muito obrigado pelo suporte!

Comment: Uma dica dica seria colocar o código fixo da pasta do lado servidor.
Quantos aos vários uploads de imagem no mesmo arquivo, você diz que a mesma página html tem vários formulários de envio ou que o lado servidor deve receber várias imagens?

Comment: A mesma página tem vários inputs, tudo foi adaptado à vontade do cliente. Minha linha acabou ficando assim: `$('#bancoimgthumb').val( 'caminho' + response.photo + '.jpg' );`. Já fiz os testes, tudo funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: O problema agora é colocar o mesmo código nos vários inputs, mas com id's diferentes, para serem gravados no banco. Tenho 1 imagem principal e 10 secundárias. Na sua opinião, qual é a melhor forma de fazer?

Comment: Você pode deixar o seletor do input dinâmico, ao invés de `$('#id_do_input').val( response.photo );`, use algo como `$( '#input_de_resposta_' + imagem_atual ).val( response.photo );` a variavel `imagem_atual` já está no seu script e poderia ser utilizado se  ela não fosse sobrescrita antes de obter a resposta.Crie um identificador provisório para a imagem e adicione no seletor do input.

Comment: Eu conversei com ele, não preciso fazer os inputs separados. Posso fazer um multiple, ele manda todas as fotos. Só preciso saber como vou salvar isso no banco, pois cada imagem tem um caminho diferente... mas vou quebrar a cabeça aqui, qualquer dúvida venho perguntar. De qualquer forma, agradeço pela sua valiosa ajuda!